# Spring - ActiveMQ - Durable Subscription - Close Connection and Resubscribe to get the offline messages

Tags: activemq-classic, spring-jms, durable-subscription

I want to implement a solution in Spring-JMS with activeMQ where I want to create a durable subscription to a topic. The purpose is that if a subscriber closes the subscription for a while and once again recreates the durablesubscription with same client id and subscription name, the subscriber should receive all the messages which were delivered during the time subscription was closed.

I want to implement the following logic mentioned in the ORACLE URL for durable subscriptions: [https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncgd/index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqNxi.gif)

[image]

But I am unable to perform this using spring-jms. As per the URL I need to get messageConsumer instance and call close() on that method to stop receiving message temporarily from the topic. But I am not sure how to get it.

Following is my configuration. Kindly let me know how to modify the configuration to perform this.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms.xsd">


<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory"
    p:userName="admin"
    p:password="admin" 
    p:brokerURL="tcp://127.0.0.1:61616"
    primary="true"
    ></bean>

<bean id="jmsContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer" p:durableSubscriptionName="gxaa-durable1" p:clientId="gxaa-client1">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    <property name="destination" ref="adiTopic"/>
    <property name="messageListener" ref="adiListener"/>
</bean>

<bean id="configTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate" 
        p:connectionFactory-ref="connectionFactory"
        p:defaultDestination-ref="adiTopic" primary="true"
        p:pubSubDomain="true">
</bean>

<bean id="adiTopic" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTopic" p:physicalName="gcaa.adi.topic"></bean>

<bean id="adiListener" class="com.gcaa.asset.manager.impl.AdiListener"></bean>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why not calling `DefaultMessageListenerContainer.stop();` to stop the container and consumers ?

you can inject `jmsContainer` to another bean and close it when you want and call start() later.

all messages sent to the broker when your durable consumer is offline will be stored until it reconnect.

to make subscription durables you need to add this to `jmsContainer` bean

```
    <property name="subscriptionDurable" value="true" />
    <property name="cacheLevel" value="1" />
```

you can add a `subscriptionName` or the class name of the specified message listener will be used.

You can add a `clientID` to the `connectionFactory`

```
    <property name="clientID" value="${jms.clientId}" />
```

or use

> `<bean class="org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory"
>           id="singleConnectionFactory">
>           <constructor-arg
>               ref="connectionFactory" />
>           <property name="reconnectOnException" value="true" />
>           <property name="clientId" value="${jms.clientId}" />
>       </bean>`

**and update jmsContainer**

> `<bean id="jmsContainer"
>           class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer"
>           p:durableSubscriptionName="gxaa-durable1" p:clientId="gxaa-client1">
>           <property name="connectionFactory" ref="singleConnectionFactory" />
>           <property name="destination" ref="adiTopic" />
>           <property name="messageListener" ref="adiListener" />
>           <property name="subscriptionDurable" value="true" />
>           <property name="cacheLevel" value="1" />
>       </bean>`

**UPDATE :**

if your `adiListener` implements `org.springframework.jms.listener.SessionAwareMessageListener` it have to define method `onMessage(M message, Session session)` and when you have the session you can call `javax.jms.Session.unsubscribe(String subscriptionName)`

subscriptionName is defined above and can be injected to this bean or the class name of the specified message listener can be used.

Comment: Thanks Hassen. It worked to deliver the messages to durable subscription when jmsContainer is started back again.

Comment: There is one issue when I started exploring the above solution. I am not able to unsubscribe completely from the durable subscription using the above solution.